VS code Shows red squiggles at RCLCPP_ERROR_STREAM
my VS code Shows red squiggles at RCLCPP_ERROR_STREAM. (RCLCPP_INFO etc.)
I'm following mtc_tutorial at moveit2 tutorials.
https://moveit.picknik.ai/humble/doc/tutorials/pick_and_place_with_moveit_task_constructor/pick_and_place_with_moveit_task_constructor.html
And I found that it has no problem when build (colcon build) but everytime it shows red squiggles at vs code and I wonder why. (I want to disappear this red squiggles) Does anybody knows about this problem?
VSCode does not recognice RCLCPP_INFO
I think this question has same question, but any of these answers worked...



